# Рандомная генерация цвета с параметрами

Tags: c#, unity3d, color

Как сделать чтобы брать за основы цвета: Жёлтый, красный, зелёный, синий, фиолетовый и сделать чтобы из этих цветов брался рандомный и этот рандомный цвет добавлять ему фиксированную тональность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай аррей в который занесены нужные цвета, а потом генерируй рандомный индекс. По индексу из аррея бери цвет.

по поводу фиксированной тональности -- вопроса не понял.